# How can I change the font in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datagrid, webforms

I am using:

```
dg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
dg.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
```

to set the background and foreground color of a `DataGrid`. How can I change the font to say Calibri or any others using the built-in methods.

Comment: Your dg object doesn't have a Font property? What type is "dg"? Okay, so we're talking about a DataGrid

Comment: I **very strongly recommend against** changing the font to "Calibri", as there's no guarantee that the user will have it installed. If this is a web application, check out a list of web-safe fonts. If it's a desktop application, let the system handle choosing the font from the user's current theme.

Comment: I want to change it to anything other than the default font. It is a web aplication.  How do I use dg.font property,, ? I am not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web application, the [`DataGrid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) already provides a [`Font` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.font.aspx) that you can set to
a font of your choosing. You can set it either from the designer or in your source code, just as you've set the `BackColor` and `ForeColor` properties.

However, as I mentioned in a comment, you should be very careful about setting controls to use a font that the user might not have installed on their computer. I recommend checking a [list of web-safe fonts](http://www.webdesigndev.com/web-development/16-gorgeous-web-safe-fonts-to-use-with-css).

Comment: Thank you. Is it something like  dg.Font = System.Drawing.Font.? I am not sure I am using it right

Comment: @Rashmi: No, the property returns a [`FontInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontinfo.aspx) that encapsulates the properties of a particular font. But you can set its properties individually. You're looking for [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fontinfo.name.aspx). So for example, try: `dg.Font.Name = "verdana";`

Comment: @Rashmi: In the future, if you don't know how to use a particular property, you can try setting it in the designer and then checking to see what code it automatically placed into your code-behind file. This particular property doesn't take a `System.Drawing.Font` object, as that describes *Windows* fonts, and this is a web application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. These suggestions help since I am new to .NET

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font with this code

```
dg.Font=new Font(string familyName,int size);
```